# Duplicate items in GridView widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-gridview

**UPDATE:** I opened an issue, please star it if you are experiencing the same problem.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28016

I have an appwidget with a gridview on it.

When I start adding items to my widget, almost always I get the first items shown twice (instead of showing the first item and second item).

If I do a widget update intent then the problem is fixed and never returns (assuming I already have two items on my gridview).

But it always happens when the first two items are added.

Any ideas what it could be?

**UPDATE:** I've just noticed that it always happens when a new item is added to the GridView. If I refresh the widget without adding a new item, then it works fine.

Another thing I saw is that the getViewAt method is always called twice for the first item (position zero). Maybe it's related?

I followed the sample here quite closely:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/src/com/example/android/weatherlistwidget/WeatherWidgetService.html

Here is my RemoteViewsService, I think this is the relevant part but I'm not sure actually.
What else can affect it?

```
package com.manor.TestApp;

public class TestAppRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService  {
@Override   
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {     
        return new TestAppViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}

class TestAppViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private Context mContext;

    //private int mAppWidgetId;

    private TestDb mDb = null;

    private int mCount = 0;

    private String[] mData;

    public TestAppViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;

        /*mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mDb = new TestDb(mContext);

        mDb.open(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mDb != null)
            mDb.close();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("TestApp", "getCount: " + Integer.toString(mCount));
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        Log.d("TestApp", "pos: " + Integer.toString(position));
        if (position    = mData.length)
            return null;

        Log.d("TestApp", "p: " + mData[position]);

        /*if (position   0) {
            Log.d("TestApp", "here");
        }*/

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
                mContext.getSharedPreferences(TestAppPreferenceActivity.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),     R.layout.widget_item);

        // --- set text and image to remoteviews --- 

        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
                mContext.getSharedPreferences(TestAppPreferenceActivity.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);

        String[] strs = mDb.getData();

        if (strs == null) {
            mCount = 0;
            return;
        }

        // -- fills mData from mDb --

        mCount = mData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: put the source class that called getViewAt()

Comment: @Rudy - the framework is calling getViewAt

Answer (score 3):

Is the height or widget of your GridView or any of its parent containers set to wrap_content?

After many days of trial and error, I think I fixed a similar issue with a ListView by changing its height from **wrap_content** to **match_parent**. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem after the change (so far).

I found a video explaining why wrap_content is bad for ListView's: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=40m45s. Maybe its similar for GridViews as well.

Comment: I hoped for this, but no.. everything is match_parent or specific size, no wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Niko's comment, I had this problem until I changed the IDs to be unique per item.

For a backing array of strings, hashing them strongly to longs, or keeping `(long id, String data)` pairs instead may help.

Here's example code for hashing. I'm using [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s `Hashing`, but the concept is general.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Hashing.sha1().hashString(mData[position]).asLong();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several trials and a month search on google, today I found the solution. When using imageviews in listview, you should initiate every imageview at each getViewAt call. I've conditioned imageview selection in each case, but forgot initialization. At getViewAt I assigned a transparent image with no content. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override public long getItemId(int pos) { return pos; }

@Override public boolean hasStableIds() { return false; }
```

Not sure if this has something to do with the problem, but the example has return true for hasStableIds()